# DataContext and Command in XAML when used together is not working

Tags: xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have a button, when i use datacontext and command, the command not work:

```
 <Button  DataContext="{Binding horaires}" Style="{StaticResource RefreshAppBarButtonStyle}" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding HomeAppBarTitle, Converter={StaticResource StringResourceConverter}}"  Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}" ></Button>
```

when i delete the datacontext and set the name manually it's work:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource RefreshAppBarButtonStyle}" AutomationProperties.Name="Actualiser"  Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}" ></Button>
```

what's can be the problem??

Best regards

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do with this : DataContext="{Binding horaires}" ?

Comment: I try to use this to change property: AutomationProperties.Name to write "Actualiser" in frensh and "Refresh" in english and the "HomeAppBarTitle" contain this value

Comment: is `RefreshCommand` in your code-behind?

Comment: refreshcommand is in my viewModel: class HorairesViewModel
    {
     
        public HorairesModel horaires { get; set; }
               public ICommand RefreshCommand { get; private set; }

Comment: Binding your button's DataContext still seems very strange.

Comment: Does `AutomationProperties.Name` use the `DataContext` of the button or the button's parent?

Comment: it use the datacontext of the button

Comment: You should clean up your tags.  This can't be wpf/silverlight/metro.  It can only be one of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does `horaires` have a property called `RefreshCommand`? I'm guessing not because you said it works without the `DataContext` being set.

You need to either remove the `DataContext` binding and change the `AutomationProperties.Name` property binding to use the `horaires` prefix like this:

```
<Button  AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding horaires.HomeAppBarTitle, Converter={StaticResource StringResourceConverter}}"  
         Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}" />
```

Or use a `RelativeSource` or `ElementName` binding to find the UI element that has your `RefreshCommand` in its `DataContext`. For example,

```
<Button  DataContext="{Binding horaires}"
         AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding HomeAppBarTitle, Converter={StaticResource StringResourceConverter}}"  
         Command="{Binding DataContext.RefreshCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" />
```

Personally, I would go with the first one because I like to avoid setting the `DataContext` explicitly if possible. The UI is supposed to reflect the data behind it, and setting the `DataContext` manually changes this hierarchy.

Comment: yes horaires have a property called RefreshCommand. The first Solution resolve my problem. thanks